# Check box user input in R?

Tags: r

Afternoon,

I was wondering if anyone knew a simple function/package for a dialogue window with check boxes that I can store user selections as objects.  For example, I'd like the prompt to be "which colors do you like" and have the user select one or more of "red, yellow, blue, green".

So, it would be similar to:

```
answerRed <- winDialogue("yesno", "Do you like red")
answerBlue <- winDialogue("yesno", "Do you like blue")
answerGreen <- winDialogue("yesno", "Do you like green")
```

except I want the user to only interact with checkboxes in one dialogue box...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly a checkbox, but it's pretty close!
Here's a link to the package's help file: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svDialogs/svDialogs.pdf

```
library(svDialogs)

colors <- dlg_list(choice = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green"),
                   title = "What colors do you like?", 
                   multiple = TRUE)$res
```